# How to Improve performance of sql recursive scalar function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I've created a SQL recursive scalar function that generate a JSON it runs for 1600 records and generates a JSON in 30 seconds i want to reduce this time how can i do this ? please the code below.

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[function_Json_by_shumail](@POSITIONID INT, @IsRoot INT ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{}', @Name NVARCHAR(MAX), @Title NVARCHAR(MAX), @Phone NVARCHAR(MAX), @Company NVARCHAR(MAX), @Email NVARCHAR(MAX) , @Children    NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Json =  
    (SELECT P.Name as name , ISNULL(P.POSTIONTITTLE,'') as title, ISNULL(P.primarycontactemail,'') as email , ISNULL(P.PRIMARYCONTACTPHONE,'') as phone , ISNULL(P.[COMPANY NAME],'') as company ,JSON_QUERY(dbo.function_Json_by_shumail(P.POSITIONID, 2) ) AS children 
    FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P  
    WHERE P.PARENTPOSITIONID = @POSITIONID
    FOR JSON AUTO);

    IF(@IsRoot = 0) 
    BEGIN
       SELECT @Name = P.Name FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.PARENTPOSITIONID is Null
       SELECT @Title = ISNULL(P.POSTIONTITTLE,'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.PARENTPOSITIONID is Null
       SELECT @Phone = ISNULL(P.PRIMARYCONTACTPHONE,'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.PARENTPOSITIONID is Null
       SELECT @Company = ISNULL(P.[COMPANY NAME],'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.PARENTPOSITIONID is Null
       SELECT @Email = ISNULL(P.primarycontactemail,'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.PARENTPOSITIONID is Null
       SET @Json =   '{"name":"' + @Name + '","title":"' + @Title + '","email":"' + @Email + '","phone":"' + @Phone + '","company":"' + @Company + '","children":' + CAST(@Json AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '}'
       SET @IsRoot = 1
    END
    IF(@IsRoot = @POSITIONID) 
    BEGIN
       SELECT @Name = P.Name FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.POSITIONID = @POSITIONID
       SELECT @Title = ISNULL(P.POSTIONTITTLE,'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.POSITIONID = @POSITIONID
       SELECT @Phone = ISNULL(P.PRIMARYCONTACTPHONE,'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.POSITIONID = @POSITIONID
       SELECT @Company = ISNULL(P.[COMPANY NAME],'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.POSITIONID = @POSITIONID
       SELECT @Email = ISNULL(P.primarycontactemail,'') FROM [dbo].[VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated] AS P WHERE P.POSITIONID = @POSITIONID
       SET @Json =   '{"name":"' + @Name + '","title":"' + @Title + '","email":"' + @Email + '","phone":"' + @Phone + '","company":"' + @Company + '","children":' + CAST(@Json AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '}'
       SET @IsRoot = 1
    END


    RETURN @Json 

END
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: Not using a scalar UDF would likely be a start; they are known poor performers. What are you actually trhying to achieve this with function? Why does it have so many subqueries (It refernences `VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated` 5 times each iteration). I *assume* `VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated` is a `VIEW`; is it a nested view? Sample data and expected results will help us help you; considering it looks like you're building JSON, why not just use `FOR JSON`?

Comment: @Larnu I'm trying to achieve organization hierarchy and i've converted the 5 `select` statements to only one but still same result. 

Yes `VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated` is a `VIEW` that is nested. But `VIEW` alone runs in 1 sec

Comment: OK I got your point.It can be fix  by knowing requirement and writing optimize script of VW_WorkerHierarchyUpdated.forget that `VIEW alone runs in 1 sec`. Point is View+UDF +Recursive not able to solve it.So better fix the Hierarchy script then decide if it will be place in View or UDF.